# Selecting the DropDownList Item Through ViewData

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am putting the current pageSize (5,10,15,20,All) in the ViewData inside the Controller. Now, I am trying to set the DropDownlist to set the selected value to the ViewData value.

```
  @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.GridItems, new SelectList(Model.GridITems, "Value", "Text",ViewData["SelectedItemItemValue"].ToString()))
```

The above does not work and the first item is automatically selected when the page calls the action.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first argument to DropDownListFor should be the item in the Model that you want the selected value to be bound to. For example, if you had a property on your model called 'SelectedItemValue' then your code should be as follows

```
 @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.SelectedItemValue, new SelectList(Model.GridITems, "Value", "Text",ViewData["SelectedItemItemValue"].ToString()))
```

(the last argument in the select list constructor is for the selected value so this assumes that you have something with a key of SelectedItemItemValue in your ViewData

Comment: My first item x.GridItems is of type List<SelectedListItem>! How should I proceed from there!

Comment: No problem. please mark if answer if you think this was helpful

Comment: does the id of the dropdownlist should match the ViewDate["key"]. i.e the id of the ddl is "mydropdownlist" then I should put ViewData["mydropdownlist"]

Comment: no you don't have to do that  in fact you can leave out the last argument of the select list constructor is only needed if you want to pre-select a specific value when that page loads. Is that what you mean??